# palatization of y- from *ga-

Tags: etymology, prefixes, phonology, historical-change, germanic-languages

## Premises

The common Proto-Germanic prefix
[**ga‑*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/ga-)
affixed to past participles was reduced in Modern English, obscuring its
historical participial morphology now beyond modern recognition, as seen
for example, in:

- [*e‧nough*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enough#Etymology).
- [*y‧clept*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yclept).
- [*a‧like*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alike#Etymology) from Old English
  *anlic*, reinforced by Old Norse *glikr*.
- [*hand‧i‧work*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handiwork#Etymology)  from
  Old English *handġeweorc* <  *hand* + *ġeweorc*.
- [*a‧mong*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/among#Etymology) from Middle English *ymong*
  and this from Old English *onġemang* from *on* “in” + *ġemang* “mingling”.
- The regional prefix *a‑* as in *a-been*, *a-scattered*, *a-muddled*,
  *a-ready* (which can still be found in southwest England and the southern
  United States).

From these examples, it seems that a simple vowel sound remained in the initial, unstressed position after any initial consonant sound before it had been worn down. We know that there had originally been one from comparison within the Germanic language family.

For several reasons that shouldn’t matter here, I still associate this
prefix with [palatal consonantal
sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_consonant) in English, such as
in:

- Modern English
  [*yearn*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yearn#Etymology_1) /jɚn/ akin to
  Danish and German *gerne* /ˈɡɛrnə/ and to Faroese
  [*gjarna*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gjarna#Faroese) /ˈdʒarna/.
- The regional [Low German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_German)
  (Plattdeutsch) for English “enough”, *jenug* with initial palatal /j/,
  (unlike standard German [*genug*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genug)
  with initial /g/).
- Also Francophone [*gently*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gently) /ˈd͡ʒɛntli/.
- The diphthongization seen in the Modern English first-person singular
  nominative pronoun [*I*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/I#Etymology_1) /aj/
  with /j/ (sometimes represented as /aɪ/, and corresponding to Latin *ego*), that is consonantal in regional [*cham*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cham), "I am".
- Modern English [*yes*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yes#Etymology)
  /jɛs/ from Old English
  [*ġīese*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giese#Old_English) /ˈji͜yːse/.

## Question

Does this prefix surface anywhere in a form that would ever sound like
*ja‑* as in English *jar* /d͡ʒɑr/, or at least like *ya‑* as in English
*yahoo* /ˈjɑhu/?

## Rational

In this case there may be some minute chance that
[*jam-packed*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463201/is-the-expression-jam-packed-of-american-origin)
could just possibly be akin to German *gepackt*, the past participle of
[*packen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/packen#eGrman) meaning “pack” and
used in virtually the same sense in German as it is in English, although
often with a leading intensifier: *voll, völlig* ∼ *full, fully*.

Comment: The [paywalled OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231077) has a remarkably detailed entry about all this matter.

Comment: *In this case there would be a minute chance that jam-packed were akin to German p.p. gepackt,* Unfortunately, this does not appear to be possible. According to the OED the first written record of **to jam** is  1719 and the etymology is *apparently onomatopoeic, and akin to cham v., champ v,*, and the noun, in the sense of "a crush" does not appear until 1805 when it is in American English. As an adj./adv it first appears in 1825 in American English.

Comment: I take that as a negative answer. I don't have access, but suppose the article doesn't touch upon the other sound change, e.g. *gently*, which remains as a possibility for the underlying question, not the least because *pack* has no clear etymology.

Comment: @Greybeard that meant "to press" from the start and appears to coincide approximately with the occurance of *jam-packed*. The etymology ("onomatopoetic") is of course to be deemed highly unreliable. *The sense of "a crush"* doesn't appear to be obviously relevant. What do you mean?

Comment: @vectory *The etymology ("onomatopoetic") is of course to be deemed highly unreliable*.You seem to have added a few words over what the OED said - I think that might have caused your confusion. I did not want to write an answer to what is a minor part of the question, as it merely dismisses the OPs suggestion. If you read the entries for *cham* and *champ* (and I suppose *chomp*) you will conclude that the etymology is very probable.

Comment: @Greybeard, *onomatopoeia* (or *-poetics*, my bad) are prone to be used variously and they conveniently excuse relaxed constraints on regular soundchange. I am not over-interpreting the source if it is an informal argument, hardly unverifiable! In fact, relaxed requirements would only play in my favour, if OED sidelines *cham* sim. vel. as a secondary influence. That I have ignored it completely is again my bad, but quite the opposite of *adding a few words*. Logically, if I didn't get to speak to a matter yet, then I am still undecided. Whereas you suddenly give primacy to the second. OK

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather negative answer, but the full explanation would take several pages

> Does the prefix surface anywhere in a form that would rhyme with ja- or at least ya-?

I have been unable to find any words that began "ga" that developed to "ja"- but absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

There is evidence to the contrary in the word "gather". In OE, this was recorded in "gegather" (brought together = united) and this appears as

> c725   Corpus Gloss. 512   Compactis, **gegædradon**,

but in eME, it appears as c1175

> Lamb. Hom. 147   An is..þet faire icunde þet is **igedered** bi-twene saule and licame.

Note how the first "g" changes to "i" which was pronounced /j/: this was as the first (softened/unemphasised) "g"[1] is replaceable by the OE letter "Yogh[2] + e" but the second, hard "g" is not, and it is the yogh + vowel *but not "a"*, because would have created the hard "g" of "gather".

However, it appears that words that began with, or contained **ia**- common in Latin - were all pronounced /dj/ and this is where the seems to originate.

That the "j" appeared in the first place, and yogh was lost, is most likely the Norman-French influence and also that of Church Latin and the transition to Modern English

The situation was further complicated by the letter "J", which was a comparatively late modification of the letter I, pronounced /dj/, akin to that of modern English di , de , in odious , hideous, (and Latin - tending more towards /j/ - iactus, iam, Iouem, maior, etc.)  and developed to  /dʒ/: Compare jump, Jove, Major).

The introduction of "J" then gave those words the initial "j".

[1]This is supported by Modern German Dialect in which, for example, "gegangen" (pp to go) is pronounced /j/egangen See Amazon music "Als wir jüngst verschütt **jegangen** waren" https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B007WHAW8Y

[2] OED: (The name of) the letter ȝ commonly used in Middle English to represent the palatal semivowel /j/, the voiced velar fricative /ɣ/, or the unvoiced velar fricative /x/.The letter ȝ developed from a form of g in Anglo-Saxon manuscript writing (ᵹ) and became distinguished from the continental form of the letter (the ancestor of modern lower-case g) in the early Middle English period.

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question as it pertained to modern regiolects. Will upvote in due time. Meanwhile I found ȝ etc. listed in wiktionary under \*ga-, just as you say. Beyond that, I see *champ* "mash" survived in Irish Engl. as well as *cham* "I am". I didn't find ME *cham*. Insofar as it was established that the phonology is plausible, it is besides the point for me to look further for particular instances to generalize the claim. I will leave it unaccepted for a while though in case anyone wants to wade in on the issue.